# Twenty thirteen theme change the height of menu sub items

Tags: css

Which css file and location allows change of sub menu item's frame height

Answer (score 0):

That would be in 'style.css' line 870 in the root folder of the theme, you can add height there:

```
.nav-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 80px; //you can add height here
}
```

i am not sure what are you trying to accomplish but i recommend to use the 'a' tag if you want the elements to be more tall, that will make the frame tall too.

```
.nav-menu li a {
    color: #141412;
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1; //using this
    padding: 15px 20px; // or this
    text-decoration: none;
}
```